# Lat & Long Data for Clustering on the basis of count of shops in each Lat & Long

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-analysis

I have Districts data with the count of shops, their respective headquarters latitude & longitude, and district Area in km2 as columns. I want to cluster these districts in such a way that I can assign a person to contact these shops. If count is more, I would assign one person for that district alone and If the count is less I would assign one person for 2 or 3 districts nearby.

You can find the data from below site
http://notepad.pw/distdata

Please explain to me which type of clustering to use and their dissimilarity types to use. Basically how to approach the problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: Define "contact". Call them by phone? Then I suggest to not use clustering at all, but rather to treat this as an allocation problem. I'd go with a standard greedy solution - assign the large ones first, then the small ones. The result will be good enough. I don't think this is a clustering problem, even though you can be sure someone is going to recommend k-means soon (though it won't work for you).

Comment: Contact is for my company person to go meet these centers/shops for business purposes. I want to know how many Associates to employ among 33 districts depending on count of centers/shops & Area of the district. So i thought cluster would tell me how many associates or district co ordinates to employ.

Comment: Clustering algorithms usually like making big clusters in dense areas. You want some resources allocation optimization.